# Is there an intuitive understanding about why chemical potential is the good quantity to think about for transport?

Tags: electrons, chemical-potential, transport-phenomena

I need to understand some very basic behavior of electron transport. The question I have is about why we need to look at chemical potential, rather than energy, to deduce if electron will move from one metal to another one.

Imagine that as below, I put in contact two metal having $\mu_1 > \mu_2$ as chemical potential for the electron. Then I know that the electrons will leave the material $1$ to go to the material $2$.

**My question is: Is my intuitive understanding provided in the following paragraphs correct ?**

$\mu$ represents the energy change when I add one electron. My material on the left will then loose an energy $\mu_1$ when an electron leaves, while the material on the right will gain $\mu_2$. As $\mu_2 < \mu_1$, it is more "energy favorable" to do this. Thus it is how the current will flow. *Is it a good intuitive understanding ?*

Let's assume that I want to reason in term of energy instead of chemical potential. I call $E_1$ the total energy of all the electrons on the material on the left, and $E_2$ the total energy of the material on the right. I assume $E_1 > E_2$. At first view it would look favorable to release an electron from the left to the right (because more energy on the left).  However, it could happen that removing one electron of the material on the left to add it on the material on the right would give a situation in which the total energy after this change will be **larger** than before. Indeed, nothing prevent in principle that removing one electron on the left would only reduce the energy of the left material by a tiny part, while adding it on the right would increase the energy of this material by a huge amount. This is why we need to reason with chemical potential which are associated to energy variation (and thus what is preferable). *Is it a good intuitive understanding ?*

**Additional question:**

All this reasoning about flows is strictly valid only at $T=0K$ right ? Because otherwise the quantity to minimize is no longer the energy but the free energy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some things may be clarified by looking up *electrochemical potential*, which is a more precise term when treating electronic transport in semiconductors and nanostructures - in particular, it directly incorporates the electric potential, i. e., the voltage bias.

Note that I do not mentiin the metals: description in terms of electrochemical potential is applicable when we are dealing with regions filled with charge carriers (thus quasi-metallic), separated by poor conductance regions - such as depletion layer in a diode, a tunneling barrier, a quantum point contact, etc. Only in this case the regions filled with the carriers can be described as being in (quasi-) equilibrium and attributed a chemical potential.

The energy levels in all these regions can be found by solving a Schrödinger equation for the confining potential - they are not dependent on the chemical potentials. Chemical potential defines the energy to which carrier-rich regions are filled with the carriers. When these are different, excess carriers from one region may pass to another one, thus producing the electric current in response to the applied bias.

Much on this subject can be learned from the books on semiconductor devices, such as those by Zee. The classical articles on the subject in th context of nanostructures are those by Landauer and Büttiker. Joe Imry's book [Introduction to mesoscopic physics](https://www.amazon.com/Books-Joseph-Imry/s?rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AJoseph%20Imry) is a good entry point as well, although it has a lot of other material.